# Google Wallet - Android Developer Sales Amount Issues

Tags: android, google-play, android-pay

I've been selling apps in Google Play for 3 years. I found out that the sales amount in Google Wallet doesn't match with the amount that I received. The amount shown in "Business insights" for "All time" is 30% more than what I received. I wondered why I received 30% less so I reported that to the Google. Google checkout team said they need to investigate but they secretly changed my record without notifying me. I kept emailing to them about the issue but they kept changing the representative and they finally advised that the issue happened because some orders are double counted. When I ask them for the double count detail for a specific month to see how the double count occurred, they refused to give the detail to me.

If you are also a developer who sells app in Google Play, I advise you check the sales amount in "Business insights" to see if you have the same issue as me.

If the answer is yes, I advise you to do the following.

1. Go to Google Wallet, click the "Business insights", check the sales amount for all time, capture a screen shot.
2. In the "Business insights", export the revenue for "All time".
3. Go to "Payouts", go to "Reports" tab and download the monthly record by pressing the down arrow icon.

You need to save these documents in a save place and it is better that you saved multiple copies in the USB thumb drives.

Then you can start emailing to Google about the issue. I hope the above procedures will help you to preserve some evidence before Google made the change on your record without notifying you.

If you are unfortunate as me, please email to me and we can unite together to find out the answer.

Comment: This isn't even a question........

Answer (score 0):

30%....
You know Google Play keep 30% on each sell you makes on Play Store ?

"Business insights" is the same amount as in the "Revenue" tab on your Play Console.

It does not remove the Play Store fee.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. But the amount still not matched even I deduct the Play Store fee.

Comment: here the number seems ok. but I have no sales since they makes the switch to Wallet on june 30 :(

Comment: Google confirmed that the amount mismatch is due to double count of the order but they are not willing to reveal the detail to me.

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can process the monthly reports (with filenames like PlayApps_201401.csv) using this tool:

https://github.com/eggheadgames/app_earnings

*Full disclosure: my company wrote and open sourced this tool after much searching for something similar. Hope it's useful to others!*